# Automate "Get Payment Update" with Magento and Athourize.net

Tags: payment, authorize.net

Here is our current process with Magento and Authorize.net and I would like to see if it is possible to automate the "Get Payment Update" sequence.

Current Process:
-Customer submitted orders and orders are set to "Payment Review" and Authorize.net sends an email alert
-Login into Authorize.net and review transactions and approve the new orders
-Login into Magento portal and click on "Get Update Payment"on individual orders. Each order are set to "Processing" status.

Proposal Process:
-Customer submitted orders and orders are set to "Payment Review" and Authorize.net sends an email alert
-Login into Authorize.net and review transactions and approve the new orders
-Automate a process within Magento to "Get Update Payment" if an order is in "Payment Review" status.

Our current process helps us with the fraud orders and would like to remain the same.  I would like to automate or schedule a job to run if an order is in "Payment Review" status check with Authorize.net.  If that order is approved, set the status to "Processing".

Thanks,

Von

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a cron job and call this function to "Get Update Payment" automatic.

```
$order->getPayment()->update();
```

The full code is under vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/ReviewPayment.php